# Want to monitor 802.11mc Fine time measurement packets . Is there any packet sniffer that allows me to get all packets/frames from link layer?

Tags: wireshark, sniffing, 802.11

I am doing a project with new fine time measurement capability introduced with 802.11mc (2016). I would like to monitor the frames for that.

Is it possible to get it using Wireshark or any other packet sniffer?

What I need is to monitor Link layer packets.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, monitoring 802.11 link layer packets is known as 802.11 Monitor Mode, and it is supported by Wireshark and tcpdump and just about any decent sniffer.